# How to avoid confusion between special characters and delimiters or separators?

Tags: punctuation

Some countries use `,` instead of `.` in a decimal. Unfortunately, a 2D coordinate, for example `(2,3,4)`, becomes ambiguous for readers.

How to avoid this?

Comment: a semicolon? perhaps

Comment: Brazil uses colon as a decimal separator. We are told to use a semicolon when dealing with non-integer coordinates, e.g. `(1,5 ; 2,5)`. __EDIT:__ In some cases, people suppress the value separator, e.g. `(1,5 2,5)`.

Comment: This seems off-topic for this site.

Comment: With the multiplication with a dot, a english user have a problem  `1.2 . 2.3` the . for the multiplication must be a median dot and I don't know how to do that. `1.2 ... 5.3` is not fine too but in these cases `.`is not a separator or delimiter !

Comment: In German one often uses a vertical line, e.g. (1,5|2,5) or a comma with additional space, e.g. (1,5, 2,5). [And I agree that this question is off-topic the way it is formulated right now.]

Comment: @Altermundus: have you tried `\ensuremath{\cdot}` command?

Comment: @Crowley  Thanks I never had the opportunity to use this median dot but In french is useful to the multiplication by a scalar ( extern multiplication scalar by vector for example). So thanks for your comment

Comment: @Caramdir Yes I think it would be preferable to reformulate the question : Something like `How to avoid confusion between special characters and delimiters or separators`

Answer (score 2):

The only case where this question is not off-topic is the case where someone like a french tex's user tries to use a list for example in a `\foreach` list.
When the `,`is a separator you need to hide your math `,` inside a tex group  `{...}`

Example

```
\foreach \n in {1,2,{2,718},3,{3,14}}
```

Now it's possible with the package `numprint` with `babel` and with `siunitx`to write numbers with dot and when you need to print the numbers to get the good syntax according to the country.