# Comma as decimal point leading to confusion

Tags: math-mode, punctuation, icomma

I'm writing a report in a language that uses decimal commas. In some cases that clashes with commas used for punctuation, causing hard to read text, e.g.:

[image]

for `$x_i \in [-1,5, 1,5]$`.

Is there a way to make this more readable?

Comment: See [How to avoid confusion between special characters and delimiters or separators?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20356)

Comment: Of course you aren't writing `\[` and `\]` for the brackets, are you?

Comment: @egreg: Oops, no I'm not.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you're using the comma as decimal separator, then you should consider using the semi-colon for the interval separator, it will be more readable:

[image: interval example]

```
$x_i\in[-1{,}5;1{,}5]$
```

(Instead of typing `1{,}5`, you can also use the `icomma` package as suggested by egreg or `\num` as suggested by Werner.)

Comment: That was the first version I tried. Looks good on the screen but I didn't like it very much when printed.

Comment: +1, semicolon should *absolutely* be used. Spacing is nice and all but even with proper spacing this is way too confusing otherwise.

Comment: @htorque: in French you would also add a thin space `\,` before the semi-colon. To my eye, it improves even further the readability of the formula, but depending on the language you're using, it might be against the rules.

Comment: +1 also from me. A semicolon should be used indeed.

Answer (score 35):

```
\usepackage{icomma}
...
for $x_{i}\in[-1,5, 1,5]$.
```

Notice the space after the comma where you want it to act as a punctuation symbol.

Comment: Nice, definitely an improvement! Yet I think it still needs additional space between the elements (like suggested by Stephen).

Comment: Trying this in 2020: this package should be installed from "was": `tlmgr install was`

Answer (score 17):

The [`siunitx` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) provides a general way of treating numbers and their decimal symbols. However, you have to explicitly encompass the numbers with `\num{...}`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

This is a range $x_i \in [\num{-1.5}, \num{1.5}]$.% ...or [\num{-1,5}, \num{1,5}]

\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

would produce

[image: Comma as decimal symbol]

Comment: This has been replaced by `output-decimal-marker` in `siunitx` version 2.

Comment: And in 2021 (but it has been that way for a while, I just don't know since when) you don't have to use the comma inside the `\num{}`: you can just use the point and change `output-decimal-marker` depending on the language you want to compile your document for.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `\;` or `\,` or `~` as space (instead of " "):

```
$x_i \in [-1,5,\;1\,1~1,5]$
```

and use a semicolon for the interval separator (as [already suggested by Philippe Goutet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24165/6865)).