# Best practice for typesetting physical quantities using siunitx

Tags: typography, best-practices, siunitx

Consider the following example.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[
  locale=DE,
  output-product=\cdot,
  product-units=single % I use this option a lot in the document, so I've defined it globally.
]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  A_a
  &= A_b - 4 \cdot A_c\\
  &= \SI[product-units=repeat]{1900 x 1500}{\mm} - 4 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \SI[product-units=repeat]{250 x 250}{\mm}\\
  &= \SI[product-units=repeat]{1.9 x 1.5}{\m} - 2 \cdot (\SI{0.25}{\m})^{2}\\
  &= \num{1.9} \cdot \SI{1.5}{\square\m} - \SI[parse-numbers=false]{2 \cdot 0{,}25^{2}}{\square\m}\\
  &= \SI[parse-numbers=false]{(2{,}85 - 0{,}125)}{\square\m}\\
  &= \SI{2.725}{\square\m}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

**Question**

What is the 'best' way to typeset this using the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package?

**Update**

Taking Jake's comments into consideration, I write

```
\num{1.9} \cdot \SI{1.5}{\square\m}
```

but isn't

```
\SI[product-units=single]{1.9 x 1.5}{\square\m}
```

better in this case, since the `1.9` comes from the quantity `1.9 m` where there is a unit involved?

Comment: The way you type it now already seems pretty good to me (except maybe the `product-units=single` in your preamble). Do you have something particular in mind that you're unhappy with?

Comment: @Jake Not really. I would just like to get different views on the subject. P.S. The `product-units=single` option is used because I use it often in the 'real' document.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer about the `product-units=single` thing: You did mention that you use it ofen in the real document, but I think that that's actually bad practice (I believe Joseph Wright would agree), because it's typically incorrect to not repeat the unit (and in the cases where it's not, the product shouldn't be part of the `\SI` command, because it doesn't syntactically belong with the unit).

Comment: @Jake Good point!

Comment: There’s an error in line four of your equation: m²×m² ≠ m² ;-)

Comment: Regarding your last point: I believe the "proper" way to use `siunitx` here would be to say `\SI[product-units=power]{1.9 x 1.5}{\m}`, which yields `1.9 x 1.5 m^2` (so the unit in the second argument is applied to both factors of the product, in the same way as it happens with the default setting `product-units=repeat`)

Comment: @Jake I didn't knew of `product-units=power`. This is really useful! Thank you for the info.

Comment: @Jake Another thing: Would you use `\SI[parse-numbers=false]{(38{,}0 + 52{,}4 + 32{,}6)}{\cm}` or `(\num{38.0} + \num{52.4} + \num{32.6})\,\si{\cm}` or something third?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: I'm not really sure about that one, but I'd probably `\SI[parse-numbers=false]{(\num{38.0} + \num{52.4} + \num{32.6})}{\cm}`, which keeps the length and the unit together. I haven't really been able to think of a situation where this would be needed: I think in the "real world", I would be using either `\SI{38.0}{\cm} + \SI{52.4}{\cm} + \SI{32.6}{\cm}` (if you want to show that there are three different lengths involved) or `\SI{123}{\cm}` (if the final length is of interest).

Comment: @Jake The problem with `\SI[parse-numbers=false]{(\num{38.0} + \num{52.4} + \num{32.6})}{\cm}` is that the numbers are not formatted. (I would like the decimal separator to be a comma.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Have you tried the `copy-decimal-marker` and `output-decimal-marker` options of `siunitx`? This would render `parse-numbers=false` unnecessary, I think.

Comment: @krlmlr No, I haven't. I'll definitely have a look at this.

Comment: @krlmlr Can you give an example of how you would use it to get the same output as, say, `\SI[parse-numbers=false]{(38{,}0 + 2 \cdot 26{,}2 + 32{,}6)}{\cm}`? (An actual answer, instead of a comment, would be great.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: I was on the wrong path. `parse-numbers=false` is better than typesetting the equation and putting `\si` behind it. I would have expected `\num{38,0}` in conjunction with `copy-decimal-marker` to work nicely, as per [Werner's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24164/8057) to a related question, but surprisingly this works in math mode `$$` but not in the `\SI` command (which also starts math mode). A `siunitx` bug?

Comment: Concerning the question whether you should write "1900 mm" or "1.9 m": This depends on how well you know the values. If you are sure, that your measurement has an error smaller than a mm, you can go with the first option. Otherwise go for an option with less significant figures (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures)